# How to write unit tests in plain C?

Tags: c, unit-testing

I've started to dig into the [GLib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLib) documentation and discovered that it also offers a unit testing framework.

But how could you do unit tests in a procedural language? Or does it require to program OO in C?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unit testing only requires "cut-planes" or boundaries at which testing can be done.  It is quite straightforward to test C functions which do not call other functions, or which call only other functions that are also tested.  Some examples of this are functions which perform calculations or logic operations, and are functional in nature.  Functional in the sense that the same input always results in the same output.  Testing these functions can have a huge benefit, even though it is a small part of what is normally thought of as unit testing.

More sophisticated testing, such as the use of mocks or stubs is also possible, but it is not nearly as easy as it is in more dynamic languages, or even just object oriented languages such as C++.  One way to approach this is to use #defines.  One example of this is this article, [Unit testing OpenGL applications](http://rastergrid.com/blog/2010/02/unit-testing-opengl-applications/), which shows how to mock out OpenGL calls.  This allows you to test that valid sequences of OpenGL calls are made.

Another option is to take advantage of weak symbols.  For example, all MPI API functions are weak symbols, so if you define the same symbol in your own application, your implementation overrides the weak implementation in the library.  If the symbols in the library weren't weak, you would get duplicate symbol errors at link time.  You can then implement what is effectively a mock of the entire MPI C API, which allows you to ensure that calls are matched up properly and that there aren't any extra calls that could cause deadlocks.  It is also possible to load the library's weak symbols using `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`, and pass the call on if necessary.  MPI actually provides the PMPI symbols, which are strong, so it is not necessary to use `dlopen()` and friends.

You can realize many of the benefits of unit testing for C.  It is slightly harder, and it may not be possible to get the same level of coverage you might expect from something written in Ruby or Java, but it's definitely worth doing.

Comment: Best answer so far.  You even show how to handle the practical need of Dependency Injection in C, which is the primary technique for isolating code-reach to achieve true unit-testing.

Answer (score 15):

At the most basic level, unit tests are just bits of code that execute other bits of code and tell you if they worked as expected.

You could simply make a new console app, with a main() function, that executed a series of test functions.  Each test would call a function in your app and return a 0 for success or another value for failure.

I'd give you some example code, but I'm really rusty with C.  I'm sure there are some frameworks out there that would make this a little easier too.

Comment: If you are still looking for a framework try this list for available c unit test frameworks: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unit_testing_frameworks#C

Comment: ah-ha excellent list.  There's even more frameworks out there than I thought.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [libtap](https://github.com/zorgnax/libtap) which provides a number of functions which can provide diagnostics when a test fails. An example of its use:

```
#include <mystuff.h>
#include <tap.h>

int main () {
    plan(3);
    ok(foo(), "foo returns 1");
    is(bar(), "bar", "bar returns the string bar");
    cmp_ok(baz(), ">", foo(), "baz returns a higher number than foo");
    done_testing;
}
```

Its similar to tap libraries in other languages.

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example of how you would implement multiple tests in a single test program for a given function that might call a library function.

Suppose we want to test the following module:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_div(int x, int y)
{
    if (y==0) exit(2);
    return x/y;
}
```

We then create the following test program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

// redefine assert to set a boolean flag
#ifdef assert
#undef assert
#endif
#define assert(x) (rslt = rslt && (x))

// the function to test
int my_div(int x, int y);

// main result return code used by redefined assert
static int rslt;

// variables controling stub functions
static int expected_code;
static int should_exit;
static jmp_buf jump_env;

// test suite main variables
static int done;
static int num_tests;
static int tests_passed;

//  utility function
void TestStart(char *name)
{
    num_tests++;
    rslt = 1;
    printf("-- Testing %s ... ",name);
}

//  utility function
void TestEnd()
{
    if (rslt) tests_passed++;
    printf("%s\n", rslt ? "success" : "fail");
}

// stub function
void exit(int code)
{
    if (!done)
    {
        assert(should_exit==1);
        assert(expected_code==code);
        longjmp(jump_env, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        _exit(code);
    }
}

// test case
void test_normal()
{
    int jmp_rval;
    int r;

    TestStart("test_normal");
    should_exit = 0;
    if (!(jmp_rval=setjmp(jump_env)))
    {
        r = my_div(12,3);
    }

    assert(jmp_rval==0);
    assert(r==4);
    TestEnd();
}

// test case
void test_div0()
{
    int jmp_rval;
    int r;

    TestStart("test_div0");
    should_exit = 1;
    expected_code = 2;
    if (!(jmp_rval=setjmp(jump_env)))
    {
        r = my_div(2,0);
    }

    assert(jmp_rval==1);
    TestEnd();
}

int main()
{
    num_tests = 0;
    tests_passed = 0;
    done = 0;
    test_normal();
    test_div0();
    printf("Total tests passed: %d\n", tests_passed);
    done = 1;
    return !(tests_passed == num_tests);
}
```

By redefining `assert` to update a boolean variable, you can continue on if an assertion fails and run multiple tests, keeping track of how many succeeded and how many failed.

At the start of each test, set `rslt` (the variables used by the `assert` macro) to 1, and set any variables that control your stub functions.  If one of your stubs gets called more than once, you can set up arrays of control variables so that the stubs can check for different conditions on different calls.

Since many library functions are weak symbols, they can be redefined in your test program so that they get called instead.  Prior to calling the function to test, you can set a number of state variables to control the behavior of the stub function and check conditions on the function parameters.

In cases where you can't redefine like that, give the stub function a different name and redefine the symbol in the code to test. For example, if you want to stub `fopen` but find that it isn't a weak symbol, define your stub as `my_fopen` and compile the file to test with `-Dfopen=my_fopen`.

In this particular case, the function to be tested may call `exit`.  This is tricky, since `exit` can't return to the function being tested.  This is one of the rare times when it makes sense to use `setjmp` and `longjmp`.  You use `setjmp` before entering the function to test, then in the stubbed `exit` you call `longjmp` to return directly back to your test case.

Also note that the redefined `exit` has a special variable that it checks to see if you actually want to exit the program and calls `_exit` to do so.   If you don't do this, your test program may not quit cleanly.

This test suite also counts the number of attempted and failed tests and returns 0 if all tests passed and 1 otherwise.  That way, `make` can check for test failures and act accordingly.

The above test code will output the following:

```
-- Testing test_normal ... success
-- Testing test_div0 ... success
Total tests passed: 2
```

And the return code will be 0.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way of doing a unit test is to build a simple driver code that gets linked with the other code, and call each function in each case...and assert the values of the results of the functions and build up bit by bit...that's how I do it anyway

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

   // call some function
   int x = foo();

   assert(x > 1);

   // and so on....

}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing intrinsically object-oriented about testing small pieces of code in isolation. In procedural languages you test functions and collections thereof.

If you are desperate, and you'd have to be desperate, I banged together a little C preprocessor and gmake based framework. It started as a toy, and never really grew up, but I *have* used it to develop and test a couple of medium sized (10,000+ line) projects.

[Dave's Unit Test](http://dut.sourceforge.net/) is minimally intrusive yet it can do some tests I had originally thought would not be possible for a preprocessor based framework (you can demand that a certain stretch of code throw a segmentation fault under certain conditions, and it will test it for you).

It is also an example of why making heavy use of the preprocessor is *hard* to do safely.

Answer (score 3):

You can write a simple minimalistic test framework yourself:

```
// test_framework.h

#define BEGIN_TESTING int main(int argc, char **argv) {
#define END_TESTING return 0;}
#define TEST(TEST_NAME) if (run_test(TEST_NAME, argc, argv))

int run_test(const char* test_name, int argc, char **argv) {
    // we run every test by default
    if (argc == 1) { return 1; }
    // else we run only the test specified as a command line argument
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(test_name, argv[i])) { return 1; }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Now in the actual test file do this:

```
#include test_framework.h

BEGIN_TESTING

TEST("MyPassingTest") {
    assert(1 == 1);
}

TEST("MyFailingTest") {
    assert(1 == 2);
}

END_TESTING
```

If you want to run all tests, execute `./binary` without command line arguments, if you want to run just a particular test, execute `./binary MyFailingTest`

Answer (score 2):

With C it must go further than simply implementing a framework on top of existing code.

One thing I've always done is make a testing module (with a main) that you can run little tests from to test your code.  This allows you to do very small increments between code and test cycles.

The bigger concern is writing your code to be testable.  Focus on small, independent functions that do not rely on shared variables or state.  Try writing in a "Functional" manner (without state), this will be easier to test.  If you have a dependency that can't always be there or is slow (like a database), you may have to write an entire "mock" layer that can be substituted for your database during tests.

The principle unit testing goals still apply: ensure the code under test always resets to a given state, test constantly, etc...

When I wrote code in C (back before Windows) I had a batch file that would bring up an editor, then when I was done editing and exited, it would compile, link, execute tests and then bring up the editor with the build results, test results and the code in different windows.  After my break (a minute to several hours depending on what was being compiled) I could just review results and go straight back to editing.  I'm sure this process could be improved upon these days :)

Answer (score 1):

I use assert. It's not really a framework though.

Comment: assert is not great for testing, because your test program will terminate at the first failure, which severely limits automated testing and test reporting.

Comment: Assert can be used as part of unit testing or part of ensuring that your functions are being called properly, but they are not "Unit Testing"